# wait until showdialog is closed flutter

Tags: flutter, wait

I am trying to get the location permissions and I want to display a message before requesting the permission. but when I run the APP it doesn't wait until I close the showdialog

```
  Future<void> checkPermission() async {
var status = await Permission.location.status;
print(status.toString());
if (status.isUndetermined) {
  await showAlertPopup(context, '',
          'OK')
      .then((val) {
    var statuses = Permission.location.request();
    print(statuses);
  });
}
if (status.isDenied ||
    status.isPermanentlyDenied ||
    status.isRestricted ||
    status.isUndetermined) {
  await showAlertPopup(context, '',
          'error')
      .then((val) {
    openAppSettings();
  });
}
if (status.isGranted) {
  _geoAlowed = true;
}
```

}

and this is my code to display the popup

```
showAlertPopup(BuildContext context, String title, String detail) async {
  showDemoDialog({BuildContext context, Widget child}) async {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: false,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return child;
        });
  }

  return showDemoDialog(
    context: context,
    child: AlertDialog(
      title: Text(title),
      content: Text(detail),
      backgroundColor: grayLight,
      actions: [
        FlatButton(
          child: Text('OK'),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context, 'OK');
          },
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As per your question, you want to request permission when user clicks 'OK' button in dialog.

You can create a callback, that is when user clicks 'OK'

```
showAlertPopup(context, '','OK', (){
  //Code you want to execute when user clicks 'OK'
  
});
```

And little changes in you showAlertPopup

```
showAlertPopup(BuildContext context, String title, String detail, Function onClick) async {
  showDemoDialog({BuildContext context, Widget child}) async {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: false,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return child;
        });
  }

  return showDemoDialog(
    context: context,
    child: AlertDialog(
      title: Text(title),
      content: Text(detail),
      backgroundColor: grayLight,
      actions: [
        FlatButton(
          child: Text('OK'),
          onPressed: () {
            //Your callback
            onClick();
            Navigator.pop(context, 'OK');
          },
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```